# Opening a .txt file in Python

Tags: python, string, list, file-io, text-files

I'm trying to open a .txt file in Python with the following function.

```
def get_my_string():
   """Returns a string of the text"""
   f = open("/home/Documents/text.txt", 'r')
   string = str(f.read())
   f.close()
   return string
```

I want "string" to be a string of the text from the opened file. However, after calling the function above, "string" is an empty list.

Comment: does this directorystructure realy exist and do you have the required permissions for this file? as it is, you should get a string-representation of the file. the str() call around the f.read, is superflous and doesn't do anythin useful.

Comment: Paste the full code with output please. There is no way you would get a `list` from that function.

Comment: You're both right. This was a silly mistake (embarrassed). I wasn't logged in as the correct user and didn't have access to the file. I think "articles" was returning as an empty list because I didn't redefine it after an earlier (unsuccessful) try that returned an empty list. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
def get_my_string():
    """Returns the file inputFn"""

    inputFn = "/home/Documents/text.txt"

    try:
        with open(inputFn) as inputFileHandle:
            return inputFileHandle.read()

    except IOError:
        sys.stderr.write( "[myScript] - Error: Could not open %s\n" % (inputFn) )
        sys.exit(-1)
```

Comment: The file will not be closed if its completely empty. It would be more compact and clear to use `with open(inputFn, 'r') as f: return f.next()`

Comment: -1 (1) this reads only the first line, which is not what the OP said he wanted (2) if there is an `IOError`, it supresses the detailed error info (file doesn't exist? caller doesn't have permissions? etc?) and gratuitously calls `sys.exit`

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer to reflect the change for item 1. I only wanted to show the `try...except` block as a way to show how to think about error checking. Sorry this upset you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the home/documents part as long as the python file and text file are saved in the same folder, you only need to open the textfile using the Open() function and the textfile name in a string so Open("text.txt") you may not need the brackets but it may work with them.